aws Lambda function run time error module Cannot find module
I want to create a lambda function by executing of that create token for get stream API but show run time error. it is my code
/**
 * @type {import('@types/aws-lambda').APIGatewayProxyHandler}
 */
const { StreamChat } = require('stream-chat');
const { Auth } = require('aws-amplify');


exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // the get stream api info
    const apiKey = 'api_key';
    const apiSecret = 'api-secret-key';

    // Initialize the Stream Chat client
    const serverClient = StreamChat.getInstance(apiKey, apiSecret);

    try {
        // Retrieve the current authenticated user
        const currentUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
        const userId = currentUser.attributes.sub;

        // Generate a token for the user
        const token = serverClient.createToken(userId);
        console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: ' jjjj Hello from Lambda ',
                token: token
            }),
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error retrieving current user:', error);
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'Error generating Stream Chat token',
                error: error.message
            })
        };
    }
};


It is the error
`Response

{
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'stream-chat'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
"trace": [
"Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'stream-chat'",
"Require stack:",
"- /var/task/index.js",
"- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
"    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)",
"    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
"    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
"    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
]`
}

How did you bundle and deploy the Lambda? Is "stream-chat" in your package.json?
